# Docker logoff Azure

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I had [ChirpStack](https://github.com/brocaar/chirpstack-docker) Docker-Compose container in my local Windows 10 PC. It was configured and running fine.

I did stupid thing. I was trying to make this system run on Azure by entering commands:

```
docker login azure
docker context create aci myacicontext
and some more ..
```

Finally I failed with Azure and now I would like my local docker run again by entering old good command that worked fine before Azure:

```
docker-compose up
```

Got error:

```
The platform targeted with the current context is not supported.
Make sure the context in use targets a Docker Engine.
```

I suppose this error is because I was loged in Azure and I executed command:

```
docker logout
```

But this not helped. How get my docker composer run on my Windows machine again?

Answer (score 4):

I faced same issue and way to solve was to change context back to default
 `docker context use default`